# Repeated jQuery POST ajax calls to a php file with output only works once

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have a few links that's values are stored in jQuery and then are used as a variable for the PHP file it calls. In that PHP file, it outputs the same exact links so the process can continue without refreshing the page. But, the second time clicking the links does not produce the jQuery POST ajax call to the php file.

Here is my jQuery code

```
jQuery('.wantedStatus').on('click', function(event)
{
    var anime_id = <?php echo $anime_id; ?>;
    var anime_list_entry_id = <?php echo $anime_list_entry_id; ?>;
    var wantedStatus = jQuery(this).tex   
    jQuery.post("/path/to/php/file/updateStatus_animelist.php", {firstParam : anime_id, secondParam : anime_list_entry_id, thirdParam : wantedStatus}, function(data) {
         //this is your response data from serv
         console.log(data);
         jQuery('#anime_list_update').html(data);
    });
    return false;
});
```

The links that activate this function.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="wantedStatus">Watching</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="wantedStatus">Plan to watch</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="wantedStatus">On hold</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="wantedStatus">Dropped</a>
```

Now these exact links are outputted from the `updateStatus_animelist.php` and so when they are clicked again, they don't work.

Comment: use `event.preventDefault()` better than all those `javscript:void(0)` intrusive handlers.

Comment: @moonwave99 removing the href from the anchor would cause it to not work properly in IE correct?

Comment: @Faeron just use `href="#"`.

Comment: Throws you to the top of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the elements are getting replaced on each call, you want to listen to `click` on either the parent or the `document`.

Please try:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.wantedStatus', function(event) {
  ...
});
```